# Ubuntu 20.04 server 'Live?' Can Not detect muti-partitions UEFI and CSM backward compatibility

Tags: dual-boot, server, partitioning, uefi, grub-efi

Unlike Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 20.04 'Live??' does not have the same capability to detect 12 partitions under the UEFI and CSM - or backward compatibility firmware configuration. Is a real "Ubuntu 20.04 server" iso available? without the word 'live' or 'dead'?

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 server and swap on the 11th and 12th partition. Can anyone tell me how can I install the new Ubuntu server 20.04 to overwrite my older Ubuntu 16.04 server version? Is it possible?

Comment: Are you asking for help troubleshooting? Or are you asking for help locating a different installer?  Or are you asking for something else? We're not there, we cannot see what you are experiencing. Most folks simply boot the Server installer and follow the prompts and it works for them. However, we also don't know how your system is different. We might be able to offer you better advice with a bit more detail and a single, clear, answerable question above. ([how to edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1257176/edit))

Comment: There are two main versions of the Ubuntu server.  The download with "live" in the name will not work with existing partitions or dual boot.  I think it can but be prepared for lots of work.  Till recently there was another server download iso that did not have the word Live in it.  That one will look for and work with existing partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, Ubuntu 20.04 lacks the capability of detecting old disk configuration like the Ubuntu 16.04 does. I saw at least one post who had the same problem on this Ubuntu 20.04 live ISO installation. I am not asking for troubleshooting. I am asking to create another version of Ubuntu server 20.XX to have the ability to detect multi-boot partitions and fully support the firmware of "UEFI and backward support" configuration like Ubuntu 16.04 does. In my case, the server 20.04 installation stopped at the 2nd or 3rd step and said it can not read the disk configuration although I had unformatted #11th prepartition or already installed 16.04 server at the #11th partition and #12th swap partition.

Comment: You just need the right ISO.  Depending on what kind of config you are looking for and the type of server you want you can install the regular ubuntu/kubuntu in the partitions you want. Then install the server applications on top.  BUT there is an iso that will look for and accomodate existing partitions.  Another option is use that ISO in 18.04. Then right away upgrade it to 20.04 form the command line. THEN do all your config and install.

Comment: Found the link.  Painful.  This will work. http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-18.04.4-server-amd64.iso